# ABP real-time notification system UserId is null

Tags: c#, .net, notifications, signalr, aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to use the real-time notification. I tried all examples but when I `SendNotificationsAsync`, my client doesn't receive it.

Also, `AbpNotifications` table is always empty.

Startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis("redis", 6379, "", "ChecklistCache");
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

Sub:

```
public async Task Subscribe_NewAlert(int? tenantId, long userId)
{
    await _notificationSubscriptionManager.SubscribeAsync(new UserIdentifier(tenantId, userId), "NewAlert");
}
```

Pub:

```
public async Task Publish_NewAlert(string alert)
{
    var msg = new MessageNotificationData($"New alert created! {alert}");
    await _notiticationPublisher.PublishAsync("NewAlert", msg, severity: NotificationSeverity.Info);
}
```

My job:

```
[Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWork]
public override void Execute(UserIdentifier args)
{
    var notifications = _userNotificationManager.GetUserNotifications(args);
    Abp.Threading.AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => _realTimeNotifier.SendNotificationsAsync(notifications.ToArray()));
}
```

1. I checked `_realTimeNotifier` and my `UserId` is null, but the `IOnlineClientManager` sets an user automatically. Where can I set my user ID?
2. To use the ABP notification system, must I have all the common tables that ABP creates? (`AbpUser`, `AbpTenant`, `AbpRoles`, permissions, etc.) Can I change those tables' names and column names? If I use external login and I don't have all that info, do I still need those tables?
3. When I set my ID at execution time, it works. Also, after the notification is shown, it's not deleted from database, so it is showing every time. Must I delete manually?

Let me try to clarify what I need:

- Every user that logs on to my website will subscribe to `"NewAlert"`.
- My API receives `"NewAlerts"` so that API will need to push this alert to all subscribers. But after that, I need to send the real-time notification to users on the website. That I don't know how to do from my Web API.

Now it is working, after I implemented authentication to my site. But my problem now is that my notifications don't expire. Every time I publish a notification, I show to my client all notifications that are on `AbpUserNotifications` table.

When do notifications expire? My understanding is that when I publish a notification, a record is created on table `AbpUserNotifications` and then I show to the client. But when I publish another notification, it is showing TWO notifications to my client. Do I need to control my notifications manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Real-time notifications

> I checked _realTimeNotifier and my UserId is null, but the IOnlineClientManager sets an user automatically, where can I set my user id?

It is automatically set from a cookie or a JWT token by the authentication (authorization) system.

## Persistent notifications

> to use the abp notification system I must have all the common tables that abp framework creates? (abpUser, AbpTenant, AbpRoles, permissions, etc) I can change those tables names and columns names too? And if I use external login, I don't have all that info, still need those tables?

No, you don't need *all* the tables. You can implement your own `INotificationStore` and services.

Module Zero, which implements the store using repositories, creates and uses the common tables.

[External login](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/User-Management#external-authentication) does create a user in a tenant in your application. That's how most applications work.

> When I set my ID at execution time works, also after the notification is shown, its not deleted from database, so is showing every time, I must delete manually?
>
> <sub>Now is working, after I implemented authentication to my site, but my problem now is that my notifications dont expire, everytime I publish a notifications is show to my Client I notifications that is on AbpUserNotifications table.</sub>
>
> <sub>When Notifications expire? My understanding is that when I publish a notification a record is created on Table AbpUserNotifications and them I show to the client, but when I publish another notifications is showing TWO notify to my client. I need to control my notifications manually?</sub>

Notifications don't expire. You should mark it as read (similar to Stack Overflow) or delete it.